# Code migration from tinymce 4 to tinymce 5 - problem with action function (true / false)

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4, tinymce-5

I have a problem with migrating the plugin from tinymce 4 to tinymka 5. The console tells me **"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: btn.active is not a function"**

I can not find an equivalent for tinymce 5. Can someone replace it?

Code below:

```js
tinymce.PluginManager.add('phonelink', function(editor, url) {
            // Add a button that opens a window
            var linkText = "";
            var linkTitle = "";
            var link = "";
            // tinymce.DOM.loadCSS(url + '/css/phonelink.css');
            editor.ui.registry.addButton('phonelink2', {
                text: 'asddas',
                icon: 'image-options',
                onSetup: updateOnSelect,
                onAction: onClickPhoneButton
            });
            // Adds a menu item to the tools menu
            editor.ui.registry.addMenuItem('phonelink', {
                text: 'asddas',
                icon: 'image-options',
                context: 'tools',
                onAction: onClickPhoneButton,
                onSetup: updateOnSelect
            });
            function onClickPhoneButton(){
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: '123213123',
                    body: {
                        type: 'panel',
                        items: [
                            {type: 'input', name: 'phone', label: 'Teléfono', value: link},
                            {type: 'input', name: 'showtext', label: 'Texto a mostrar', value: linkText},
                            {type: 'input', name: 'title', label: 'Título', value: linkTitle}
                        ]
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'Close',
                            type: 'cancel',
                            onclick: 'close'
                        },
                        {
                            type: 'submit',
                            name: 'submitButton',
                            text: 'Stwórz',
                            primary: true
                        }
                    ],
                    onAction: function(e) {

                        alert('Toggle menu item clicked');
                    },
                    onSubmit: function(e) {
                        var data = e.getData();
                        var hrefLink = '<a title="' + data .title + '" href="tel:+34' + data .phone + '">' + data .showtext + '</a>';
                        if(link !== ''){
                            editor.setContent(hrefLink);
                        }else{
                            editor.insertContent(hrefLink);
                        }

                        e.close();
                    }
                });
            }
            function updateOnSelect() {
                var btn = this;

                const editorEventCallback = function (e) {

                    var node = editor.selection.getNode();
                    var isTelLink = node.href !== undefined && node.href.indexOf('tel:+') !== -1

                    btn.active(isTelLink);

                    if(isTelLink){
                        link = node.href;
                        link = link.replace("tel:+34", "");
                        linkTitle = node.title;
                        linkText = node.text;
                    }
                };
                editor.on('NodeChange', editorEventCallback);
                return function (btn) {
                    editor.off('NodeChange', editorEventCallback);
                }

            }
        });
```

I searched the documentation for a replacement, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE 5 no longer passes the button and menu instance via `this`. Instead it passes an API instance as the first parameter, so you'll want to change your `updateOnSelect` function to something like this:

```js
function updateOnSelect(api) {
    const editorEventCallback = function (e) {

        var node = editor.selection.getNode();
        var isTelLink = node.href !== undefined && node.href.indexOf('tel:+') !== -1

        api.setActive(isTelLink);

        if(isTelLink){
            link = node.href;
            link = link.replace("tel:+34", "");
            linkTitle = node.title;
            linkText = node.text;
        }
    };
    editor.on('NodeChange', editorEventCallback);
    return function (btn) {
        editor.off('NodeChange', editorEventCallback);
    }
}
```

You'll note `var btn = this` has been removed and that the API to set an item as active is `setActive` instead of `active`. This can be found in the  documentation here: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/typesoftoolbarbuttons/#togglebutton and https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/menuitems/#togglemenuitems (see the API section in both links).

In the above, you may have noticed both reference "Toggle" items. That's another change in TinyMCE 5, as different types of buttons/menu items have a separate registration API. So you'll also need to swap to using `editor.ui.registry.addToggleButton` and `editor.ui.registry.addToggleMenuItem`. More details about that can be found here if needed: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/migration-from-4x/#customtoolbarbuttons

Here's an example fiddle showing the changes mentioned above: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/B5haab.

Hopefully that helps!